# Tensor product of irreducible representations is irreducible

Tags: representation-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. All considered representations are linear. Suppose $G$ is a group, not necessarily finite.

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are irreducible, finite dimensional representations of $G$ over $k$. Is it the case that $V\otimes W$ is irreducible as a representation of $G$? I think the answer is affirmative if we consider the tensor product representation on $G\times G$ as a consequence of the density theorem, but I'm not sure about the question I ask.

Comment: As a representation of $G$? No. For example, $V\otimes V=\mathrm{Sym}^2 V \oplus \wedge^2 V$ is irreducible if and only $V$ is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, the answer is definitely no. The task of writing the tensor-product of two irreduciple representations as a sum of irreducible representations is known as the "Clebsch-Gordan problem", and can be quite intricate depending on the group in question.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_representations#Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_theory) for some general remarks, or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) for a detailed discussion in the $SU(2)$ case (which is is important in physics, and therfore very well developed).